# Get exif version - iOS

Tags: ios, image, exif

I have a jpeg image, and i am trying to add exif information to it. There is a field called 'Exif Version', whose key is represented as `kCGImagePropertyExifVersion`. Where do I get its value? Does it vary from phone to phone? or does it vary among different OS versions? Or is it different for different cameras?
but how do I know the version for a particular device?

(I have tried to search a lot on the internet, but I don't get any information on this)